# Как исправить метериал в unity

Tags: unity3d

Как можно исправить то, что объекты с противоположной стороны к освещению черные?

[image: изображение]

Comment: добавьте ambient light на сцену

Comment: Windows/Rendering/LightingSettins Enviroment/EnviromentLight - AmbientColor

Answer (score 0):

Нажимаем Window-Rendering-Lighting Settings
В Environment мы ищем Environment Lightning и в Ambient Light выставляем Baked.
Затем ставим галку напротив Realtime Global Illumination и чуть ниже еще у Baked Global Illumination.